# What java class can I use to read GAE's blobstore's serve using retrofit

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore, retrofit

I'm using GAE's blobstore and I'm returning a file using the blobstore's serve method that puts the file on the response. On the client side I'm using retrofit. Does anyone know how I can read the response using retrofit? Do I declare the method as returing a specific class or do I need to also change the converter so it doesn't try to read it using the Gson converter?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not familiar with Retrofit, using Blobstore to serve a response in a RESTful way won't work very well. As per BlobstoreService.serve [1]:

"response should be uncommitted before invoking this method, and should be assumed to be committed after invoking it. Any content written before calling this method will be ignored."

You can't simply include the blob as part of a JSON response, you're just going to get the blob. If you can change Retrofit's converter so it doesn't try to interpret the response as JSON, that would be the way to go.

A more complete solution is to use Cloud Storage instead of Blobstore, so you can read from it while building a proper JSON response in your handler. Blobstore is more of a "quick and dirty" way to handle uploading files and serving them back.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService
[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob
[3] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/

Comment: Thank you, I did make a note for myself back then to change to use Cloud Storage when I have time to make that change. For now I just had the used the blobstore serve method which as you said fills the body of the response, in retrofit if you set the return of the interface method as Response it works. Thanks.